# SQL Server - OLEDB queries get stucks SOMETIME

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, oledb, threshold

I was being experience SQL Server issue that OLEDB queries get stucks sometime in PRODUCTION, cannot kill it, and have to restart SQL service at night.

Example Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM OpenDataSource('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Data Source="C:\Temp\";User ID=;Password=;Extended properties="Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited()"')...[ve01#csv]
```

Basically, we're changing to use SSIS to replace it, but we still use it as much.

Does someone know how much the limitation or threshold that OLEDB query will be stucks? Or any sharing ideas for it please?

Thanks alot.